# Recharts - How to preserve edge value of Y-Axis?

Tags: d3.js, recharts

I have a chart with proper display of data, but my Y-Axis is linear (should be) and it crops data (see screenshot).

I expect Y-Axis to show linear data AND respect the edge (max) value of the chart.

I was trying to work with d3-scale but I failed - don't know how to "append" max value to the scale. The only way I figured is to manually calculate all the ticks which I'd like to avoid.

[image]

My Y-Axis code is

```
<YAxis
  domain={[data.yAxis.min, data.yAxis.max]}
  scale="linear"
  tickFormatter={formatEnergyAxis}
/>
```

Where `min` is `0` and `max` is 3200 (unit conversion happens in formatters).

Is there a way to adjust the scale?

Comment: Are you saying that the largest bar should actually be longer, but it isn't?

Comment: The opposite - the bar is bigger than te larger Y axis tick. Linear scale is multiplying every 0.5kWh, I need last tick to be "extra

Answer (score 0):

If possible, call the function [`.nice()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_nice) inside `YAxis`. Otherwise, call it before passing the values to the binding:

```js
d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 3200]).nice().domain()
// [0, 3500]
```

That would be

```js
<YAxis
  domain={d3.domain([data.yAxis.min, data.yAxis.max]).nice().domain()}
  scale="linear"
  tickFormatter={formatEnergyAxis}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your Y-Axis, you can specify your last tick to be visible with the props `interval` set to `preserveEnd`, like this:

```js
<YAxis
  domain={[data.yAxis.min, data.yAxis.max]}
  scale="linear"
  tickFormatter={formatEnergyAxis}
  interval="preserveEnd"
/>
```

You can also use the  value `preserveStartEnd` to be have the root & edge values visible.

Comment: It doesnt work, because it doesnt even generate the last tick. Its relate to d3-scale more likely